# How to delete Views under Jenkins without affecting existing jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to delete Views under Jenkins without affecting the Jobs under the view. I am asking this since I am not able to enter same name of View even after deleting this as an Administrator.

I checked Config file under Jenkins folder and tried editing the View name but that didn't work.

I need a confirmation whether below script will delete the View name only or along with Jobs under view.

**BE AWARE the following scriptlet deletes all your jobs!!!**

```
Jenkins.instance.getView("MyView").items.each { item ->
    println "deleting $item.name"
    item.delete()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

go to view --> edit view --> unchecked all jobs on that view --> Save --> Delete View

Comment: I didnt find any option of " unchecked all jobs on that view --> Save --> Delete View."
Added the screenshot.
Jenkins Version - 1.652

Comment: This is not any option, this is what you have to `un-check` jobs which are checked under that view.

Comment: Ahh your jenkins version is pretty old 1.652, you can go by DSL using jenkins.instance.deleteView(<your_view_name>)
Check the behavior in jenkins_url/script

Comment: If your view is 'Default View' then first un-select that view as default, then and then only you can delete view.

Comment: @Kally it's maybe because you created `My View` instead `List View`.

Answer (score 6):

For deleting a view (and not touching any jobs therein) use

```
def view = Jenkins.instance.getView("MyView")
Jenkins.instance.deleteView( view )
```

Your code deletes the jobs in the view (but not the view itself), so be careful with that : )

Comment: run this in the script console found under manage jenkins > script console