# Delete view programmatically in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to delete a Jenkins view programmatically but my Jenkins job:

```
import jenkins.model.*;
import jenkins.util.*;

jenkins = Jenkins.instance

def view = jenkins.getView("my-view")
jenkins.deleteView( view )
```

fails giving:

```
[workspace] $ groovy /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DeleteViews/workspace/hudson8664703220024294601.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson8664703220024294601
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson8664703220024294601
    at hudson8664703220024294601.run(hudson8664703220024294601.groovy:4)
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
```

I've seen solutions like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020732/343204

and suggestions on how to import like this:

[Running Groovy command from Jenkins using Groovy script plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429050/running-groovy-command-from-jenkins-using-groovy-script-plugin)

but not sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you use freestyle job with step "**Execute Groovy script**".
So, you need to change this step to "**Execute system Groovy script**" and your code will work.